# Can the single object accelerate? (Relativity theory)

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, relativity

Suppose space is empty except for one single object.

According to relativity theory it doesn't matter whether we assign a constant velocity to it or not; in both scenarios the same is predicted.

The same cannot be said when comparing the object with a constant vs changing velocity - when assigned an acceleration, the object would feel something similar to gravitational pull.

Does it make sense to be able to assign an acceleration to the single object?

Comment: If a tree falls in the forrest and nobody is around to hear it, does it make a sound? You are basically asking the same thing.

Comment: even if it's just an isolated object, how technically do you create the impulsion without splitting it ?

Comment: @CuriousOne that's a phylosophical question about the definition of 'sound'. A physicists answer would be "Yes, it would create sound". I don't see the relevance of the physolophical question.

Comment: @Angelsdorf: A physicist will have a laugh and leave you to your little mind games. Physics is a natural science. It only cares about what exists in nature, not what exists in your mind.

Comment: @CuriousOne that is an extremely naive view of natural science. I bet that any question on any test of any natural science class involved hypothetical scenario's which didn't precicely describe a real life existing scenario. Natural science is about finding laws which apply to the actual world and extend to any thinkable scenario; otherwise they wouldn't be predictive.

Comment: @Angelorf: Tests are necessary to grade and ultimately discipline lazy students, neither nature nor science cares about them. You got your definition of science wrong already. In a well designed test that would be a loss of points, right there.

Comment: @CuriousOne I am offended by your last post. I suggest you do some reading up on counterfactuals and hypotheticals.

Comment: I think my question is philosophical in nature, which might make it hard to understand for phycisists. However, John Rennies answer and its comments fully address the issue and solve my philosophical problem. I think that what was unclear to some might already be clear to others. I therefore hope the question will be put off hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite correct that for a single isolated object the velocity can be assigned any arbitrary value. That is because velocity can be measured relative to any other object so it doesn't have any single well defined value. However an isolated observer can measure their acceleration in their rest frame, and this is called their [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration).

Strictly speaking the proper acceleration can still only be measured relative to some other object because the measurement requires to to drop something and see how fast it accelerates away from you. For example right now I'm experiencing an acceleration of 1G, and I know this because if I drop my pen it accelerates away from me (towards the ground) at 1G. The astronauts in the International Space Station are weightless because when they drop a pen it stays floating in the air next to them. However the proper acceleration measurement differs from a velocity measurement because it is relative to a well defined reference i.e. a freely falling object. That's why the proper acceleration has a well defined value while velocity does not.

Comment: While space is empty, how can a single object fail ?

Comment: I'm glad someone is considering the casus in abstraction from where the acceleration would come from. I was thinking that when the object is the only one, its mass would pinn the 'aether' down. Any assignment of an acceleration to the object would then merely be the definition of an accelerating frame of reference which wouldn't affect the object at all. What do you think?

Comment: @Angelorf: you're describing [Mach's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle) or at least one form of it. Since Mach's principle is fundamentally untestable I consider it superfluous to modern physics. Sorry.

Comment: I'm unable to find any definition of a principle in physics attributed directly to Mach, though the question he raises is certainly along my lines of thinking. "Einstein realized that the overall distribution of matter would determine the metric tensor, which tells you which frame is rotationally stationary." I think this is how Einstein answered the question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_theory mentions there is debate on whether Machs words are to be interpreted as stating a principle. Thanks for the link anyway! Great help!

Answer (score -1):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether#Einstein.27s_views_on_the_aether) "special relativity does not necessarily rule out the aether, because the latter can be used to give physical reality to acceleration and rotation."

It can therefore make sense to assign an acceleration, namely w.r.t. the aether.