# Empty space and velocity

Tags: spacetime, velocity

If there was a universe without anything in it except you in a space rocket how you would you know what your velocity  if you kept the engine on?

Comment: your velocity with respect to **what**?

Comment: So you can't have velocity in empty space?

Comment: You can have velocity, but it is not an absolute concept. It is not properly defined unitl you pick a reference frame. What RF would you like to use? There is the obvious frame: one fixed to the rocket. What would your velocity be in this RF?

Comment: Why would you care?  In a hurry to get nowhere?

Comment: If you kept accelerating would your mass increase?

Comment: In order to accelerate you have to decrease your mass. What you are thinking about is "relativistic mass" and that's relative to something else, yet, again. In essence your question stopped making sense at the words "without anything".

Comment: Didn't make sense to you.

Comment: Doesn't make sense at all, physically. You've removed reference frames from a question which can only be answered with reference frames. You can only ever tell how fast you are going relative to something else: there's no "absolute velocity."

Comment: It makes perfect sense.

Comment: Your edit changed only one word, but it was an important one.  You changed the basic question, so that now the previous answers and comments no longer make sense.  Please don't do that.  Start a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity is not an absolute quantity - it is only ever defined relative to something else. If there are no other objects then you cannot assign any value to your velocity.

You use the phrase:

> if you kept the engine on

which implies you're thinking about a rocket firing its motor in empty space. Unlike velocity acceleration can be defined without reference to external objects, and this quantity is called the [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration). For more on this see my answer to [Can the single object accelerate? (Relativity theory)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227209/can-the-single-object-accelerate-relativity-theory).